# Sale of principal's tickets by an agent above face value

Tags: united-kingdom, fraud, claims, agency

If a ticket seller who is engaged as the agent of a production company (principal) sells some of the tickets at a higher price than the production company sets and pockets the difference, can the production company recover some of that money?

Comment: What does the contract between the principal and agent say about it?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

Subject to their contract, all earnings of an agent (employee or otherwise), belong to the principal. This is a well established common law principle dating back to the 18th century.